# IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error: [blank]

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I have been attempting to use pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf, but when I use it, I get the following error with the final error blank:

```
 File "email_app.py", line 118, in <module>
    send_mail()
  File "email_app.py", line 114, in send_mail
    RECEIPT_UNITS_YTD, RECEIPT_COST_YTD, RECEIPT_UNITS_MONTH_YOY, RECEIPT_COST_MONTH_YOY, RECEIPT_UNITS_YTD_YOY, RECEIPT_COST_YTD_YOY)
  File "/local/scripts/algos.py", line 1321, in no_issue
    pdfkit.from_file('/local/scripts/file'+VENDOR_ID+'.html','VendorScorecard_'+VENDOR_ID+'.pdf',cover='/local/scripts/cover'+VENDOR_ID+'.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 46, in from_file
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 119, in to_pdf
    raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr.decode("utf-8")))
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
```

Additionally, you can see the snippet of code where pdfkit.from_file is called:

```
f = open("file"+VENDOR_ID+".html","w")
cover = open("cover"+VENDOR_ID+".html","w")
email = open("email"+VENDOR_ID+".html","w")
email_body = email.write(text+no_issues)
asin_det = f.write(asin)
t = cover.write(body)
f.close()
cover.close()
email.close()
pdfkit.from_file('/local/scripts/file'+VENDOR_ID+'.html','VendorScorecard_'+VENDOR_ID+'.pdf',cover='/local/scripts/cover'+VENDOR_ID+'.html')
```

I have scoured the internet to find an answer, but most of them suggest that I need to install xvfb, which I have already done. In fact, if I just run `wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf`, it works like a charm. I'm on a Linux with Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run the exact same code on a Windows desktop, it works as intended -- spitting out a really beautiful PDF.

Comment: try running wkhtmltopdf manually, do you see a detailed error?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, running wkhtmltopdf manually on my Linux works fine. Are you suggesting I run it manually in my Python script?

Comment: try running it manually with your desired url. there's a chance you'll  see some more detailed errors

e.g. `wkhtmltopdf /local/scripts/file<vendor id>.html file.pdf`. In addition, could you add a snippet of your html cover and content?

Comment: Update: after trying the original code above without the cover = "[....]", it worked properly, so something in the cover is causing an error.